# Submit PHP Variables to Another Domain

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit

I'm trying to submit a URL from my website to another website (we'll call it domain b) with PHP variables included in the URL.

When I hit the submit button on my PHP form I need it to create a URL in the following syntax:

```
http://domainb.com/submissions.cfm?name=phpvariable1&name2=phpvariable2
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: hint: forms may be generated from php but are HTML.

Comment: Does domain 'b' require a POST or a GET operation? If it's just a GET, then use `file_get_contents( "http://domainb.com/submissions.cfm?name=phpvariable1&name2=phpvariable2" )` - easy! If it's a POST (and I suppose a submissions form sounds like it _ought_ to be a POST) then yes, `cURL` is the way to go.

Comment: set form's `action` to your precious domain and set its method to `get` =)

Answer (score 2):

It's basic html

```
<form method="get" action="http://domainb.com/submissions.cfm">

<input name="test1" type="text" value="aaa" />
<input name="test2" type="text" value="bbb" />
<input  type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

the url when you click will look like http://domainb.com/submissions.cfm?test1=aaa&test2=bbb

you can also use post action or more advanced way by curl. Moreover, there is no "php form". The forms are displayed by browser which uses HTML it's called **FRONTEND**, PHP cannot show forms because it's **BACKEND**. Browser doesn't care if it is PHP, RUBY or your own language. To show page it needs HTML that's all.

Curl example as **POST**:

```
 <?php
 $ch = curl_init('http://domainb.com/submissions.cfm');
 $encoded = '';
 $variables = array('test1' => 'aaa', 'test2' => 'bbb');
 foreach($variables as $name => $value)
   $encoded .= urlencode($name).'='.urlencode($value).'&';


 $encoded = substr($encoded, 0, strlen($encoded)-1); //remove last ampersand
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $encoded);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```